# Indentation in newtheorem environment

Tags: environments, indentation, theorems

I already have a personalization of the "newtheorem" environment, as follows:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{amsfonts}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[dvipdfm]{color}
        \usepackage[francais]{babel}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage{framed}
\theoremstyle{definition}
        \newtheorem{definitionT}{Définition}[section]
        \newenvironment{definition}{\begin{leftbar}\begin{definitionT}\par\leavevmode\par\noindent}{\end{definitionT}\end{leftbar}} \begin{document}
    \begin{definition}
    Example
    \end{definition}
    \end{document}
```

It makes a left vertical black line along my environment "definition" 
I tried to make the text start at a new line and not to be indented, but it is slighlty indented. How could I get rid of this indentation?

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please provide a full minimal example, containing preamble etc. That makes it a LOT easier to help (update your question with the mwe)

Comment: I don't think you can do `\newenvironment{def}`.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your recommendations (and your welcome). I edited my question, adding the preamble and modifying "def" to "definition" (it is "definition" in my .tex file).

Comment: That is still not a minimal example, it has no body. Basically an mwe is a (in theory) fully compilable document, where others does not have to add anything in order to test the code.

Comment: You might want to look into the following packages: mdframed or tcolorbox

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer: See how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Read the linked answer, please.

Comment: Please excuse me, I didn't know it worked that way on this website. I read this link, but my post is fully compilable now.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for the packages. Still, if it is possible to solve my problem keeping my actual packages, I'd prefer that way. If it is not, no problem, I'll try to solve it with the above packages.

Comment: That is very easy to do. You just need to make your own theoremstyle that will make the line break for you without the extra stuff in the left bar wrapper. This is explained in the amsthm manual. If you use ntheorem instead of amsthm, that style is even provided for you.

Comment: Thanks to you for your answers and patience (@daleif, @egreg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\ignorespaces` after `\noindent`; the space you see comes from the end-of-line after `\begin{definition}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{color} % better than `dvipdfm`
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{framed}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definitionT}{Définition}[section]
\newenvironment{definition}
  {\begin{leftbar}%
   \begin{definitionT}%
   \par\mbox{}\par\noindent\ignorespaces}
  {\end{definitionT}%
   \end{leftbar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
Example
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `\ignorespaces` it looks like this

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that get you into problems if you start your theorem with a blank line in the code? Not that uncommon to see in some of the manuscripts that I edit.

Comment: @daleif Of course. I just fixed the OP's problem.

Comment: Then it is just a note for future visitors to this question.